# e-commerce website individualized profiles

Tags: php, html, jquery, e-commerce, store

I'm creating an e-commerce website for local businesses here, where in my admin panel i can add a new business or store, and the store owner can access his admin page and start adding products of his store, then users can shop and buy from there, i'm not using any front end frameworks, just html css (bootstrap), javascript (jquery), and i use php/mysql for my backend and hostinger for hosting. I don't want to do subdomains for each store, i want to do it like this:
mysite.com/store/storename/home, what is the best practice here? should i use url variables to define every store and fetch data for it? for example :
mysite.com/store/storename/home?id=231&item=234xw1 ,
if not, how do you advise me to do it? after i have all the data to show for users. what is the best way?
if i have to read about something, please tell me. and thanks!!

Comment: The most common solution for this is called a _"router"_. If you look for _"php router"_ you'll find lots of information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.